# Changing recursive Closure to TrampolineClosure in Groovy

Tags: recursion, groovy

I need to construct all possible binary representations from a string containing only the characters `0`, `1`, and `V` (the wildcard). The string may be of any length (over 1000 characters) though the number of wildcards is less than 20.

For example, for the input `V1V` the output would be `[010, 011, 110, 111]`

My current implementation works but overflows the stack with a modest number of wildcards.  The code is [running here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5635093192245248) and shown below.

```
def permutts
permutts =
{
  if (!it.contains('V'))
    return [it]

  def target = it
  def res = []

  ['0', '1'].each
  {
    def s = target.replaceFirst(~/V/, it)
    if (s.contains('V'))
    {
      res += permutts(s)
    }
    else
    {
      res << s
    }
  }
  res
}
println permutts('V1V')
```

I've attempted to follow some of the examples of using `trampoline()` but I'm not even sure if that's the right approach.  [The API says](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#trampoline%28%29), "...the function is supposed to perform one step of the calculation..." but each step performs two actions: substituting in `0` and `1` for `V`.

Here's one of my attempts, which can be [run here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5701751084679168).

```
def permutts

permutts =
{ it, res = [] ->
  println "entering with " + it + ", res=" + res
  if (it.contains('V'))
  {
    def s = it.replaceFirst(~/V/, '1')
    permutts.trampoline(s, res)

    s = it.replaceFirst(~/V/, '0')
    permutts.trampoline(s, res)
  }
  else
  {
    res << it
  }
}.trampoline()
println permutts('VV')
```

The output is:

```
entering with VV, res=[]
entering with 0V, res=[]
entering with 00, res=[]
[00]
```

At least it's doing something but I don't understand why it doesn't keep going.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong or suggest a different way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Groovy's `trampoline()`provides [tail call optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization), so it should be used for closures/methods that invoke themselves in the last instruction executed (tail).

Hence, a better solution would be a classic "head/tail" processing (added println to track calls):

```groovy
def permutts
permutts = { s, res ->   
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        println "s = $s, res = $res"
        res
    } else {
        println "s = $s, res = $res"
        if (s[0] == 'V') { // s[0] ~ list.head()
            res = res.collect({ it = it + '0' }) + res.collect({ it = it + '1' })
        } else {
            res = res.collect({ it = it + s[0] })
        }

        permutts.trampoline(s.substring(1), res) // s.substring(1) ~  list.tail()
    }
}.trampoline()
```

Examples:

```
permutts('VV', [''])     
  s = VV, res = []
  s = V, res = [0, 1]
  s = , res = [00, 10, 01, 11]
  Result: [00, 10, 01, 11]

permutts('0V0', ['']) 
  s = 0V0, res = []
  s = V0, res = [0]
  s = 0, res = [00, 01]
  s = , res = [000, 010]
  Result: [000, 010]
```

Regarding your code, from `TrampolineClosure` javadoc:

> A TrampolineClosure wraps a closure that needs to be executed on a
>   functional trampoline. Upon calling, a TrampolineClosure will call the
>   original closure waiting for its result. If the outcome of the call is
>   another instance of a TrampolineClosure, created perhaps as a result
>   to a call to the TrampolineClosure.trampoline() method, the
>   TrampolineClosure will again be invoked. This repetitive invocation of
>   returned TrampolineClosure instances will continue until a value other
>   than TrampolineClosure is returned. That value will become the final
>   result of the trampoline.

That is, the substitution that is made in the tail call optimization. In your code, the whole chain of `TrampolineClosure`s returns as soon as one of them does not return a TrampolineClosure.

From groovy 2.3, you can use `@TailRecursive` AST transformation for tail call optimization:

```groovy
import groovy.transform.TailRecursive

@TailRecursive
List permutts(String s, List res = ['']) {   
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        res
    } else {
        res = (s[0] == 'V') ? res.collect({ it = it + '0' }) + res.collect({ it = it + '1' }) : res.collect({ it = it + s[0] })       
        permutts(s.substring(1), res)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Just to complete my answer, the above can be done in one line with the [functional fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29), which in Groovy is [inject](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#inject(groovy.lang.Closure)) (uses the head of the collection as the inital value and iterates over the tail):

```
assert ['000', '010'] == ['0', 'V', '0'].inject([''], { res, value -> (value == 'V') ?  res.collect({ it = it + '0' }) + res.collect({ it = it + '1' }) : res.collect({ it = it + value }) })
assert ['00', '10', '01', '11'] == ['V', 'V'].inject([''], { res, value -> (value == 'V') ?  res.collect({ it = it + '0' }) + res.collect({ it = it + '1' }) : res.collect({ it = it + value }) })
```

Comment: This is brilliant...it's clean and understandable. It's the best example of trampolining I've seen and I understand it now, at least much better than I did before.  It's taught me more about Groovy too. I'm going to wait a day to accept your answer so I can award a bounty to you as well.  Thank you for taking the time to craft such a great response.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm pleased it helped. Thank you for your encouraging message. Just added an example of how can it be done with groovy's inject.